# how to get frame from android videoview with setVideoURI streaming from external device?

Tags: android, bitmap, streaming, android-videoview

i'm making and android application that stream a video from external source and display it in a videoview in my activity.
The stream working fine, but i'm unable to save a frame on my sd card. this is my code where vv is videoview:

```
int currentPosition = vv.getCurrentPosition(); //in millisecond

        MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(viewSource);

        Bitmap bmFrame = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(currentPosition * 1000); //unit in microsecond

        if(bmFrame == null){
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
               "bmFrame == null!", 
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
             AlertDialog.Builder myCaptureDialog = 
               new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
             ImageView capturedImageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
             capturedImageView.setImageBitmap(bmFrame);
             LayoutParams capturedImageViewLayoutParams = 
               new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
             capturedImageView.setLayoutParams(capturedImageViewLayoutParams);

             myCaptureDialog.setView(capturedImageView);
             myCaptureDialog.show();
```

this is my video test url:

```
public String viewSource = "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov";
```

i try to set viewSourc for 'setdatasource' of the mediametadataretriver like the url to my video, but it return always null bitmap...

where is the problem?

Thankyou

Answer (score 3):

This class has a lot of problems and I think one of them is the frame retrieving from a external source. I would suggest you to use [this external library](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever). You only have to add it into your project and next use the class like you do with the mediametadataretriever class.

Hope it´s useful